# Springboot client server architecture

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

Created Eureka discovery client and server architecture. In client there is userInfo service CRUD opeartion. Its showing error while starting . Error is Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesBeans' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2626b418].

Comment: can u solve it ?  i have same problem and in new in java

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with the Spring boot version and Spring Cloud version. As per the reference [Deprecated ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata is removed in Spring Boot 2.3.0.M1](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1543), the reported class is deprecated.

Please choose the correct version of Spring Boot and Spring Cloud to continue, refer to [Release train Spring Boot compatibility](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud)

Pasting my pom.xml version for reference, hope it helps:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>15</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```